# Redirect to URL in json response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two files fetch.php and index.php. The fetch.php file does a search and converts the results to Json.

Index.php has Jquery which loops through the Json result. One of the cells contains a URL. How can I get a user to redirect to the URL.

```
//index.php==============================
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {

    $('#total_records').text(data.length);

    var html = '';
    if(data.length > 0)
    {
     for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
     {
      html += '<hr>';
      html += '<tr>';
      html += '<div>'+data[count].title+'</div>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].book+'</td><tr/>'; 
      html += '<br/><td>'+data[count].description+'</td><tr/>';
      html += '<td><button> VIEW </button> '+data[count].url+'</td>'; //Is there a way to redirect to this URL by clicking on the VIEW button 
      html += '<hr>';

     }
    }
    else
    {
     html = '<tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
    }
    $('tbody').html(html);
   }
  })
 }

 $('#search').click(function(){
  var query = $('#search_id').val();
  load_data(query);
 });

</script>
```

Comment: If one of the parts of the data is a URL, you can update the `window` object. This will be immediate. Or do you mean you want to create a link where the user can click on it?

Comment: Do you mean that once the response has been received that the client's page is changed? Or, do you want to present an a href to allow them to click to another page?

Comment: <button onclick="window.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';"> VIEW </button>

Comment: @Lee Basically I would like the user to click on the button and be redirected to the URL in the JSON data. The URL (+data[count].direct_applicant) prints to screen but I want to put it in the button for the user to click and go the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
html += '<td><button onclick="window.location.href=\''+data[count].url+'\'"> VIEW </button> '+data[count].url+'</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following suggestions:

```
$(function() {
  function load_data(q) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "fetch.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        query: q
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#total_records').text(data.length);
        var row;
        if (data.length > 0) {
          $.each(data, function(k, d) {
            row = $("<tr>");
            $("<td>").html(d.title).appendTo(row);
            $("<td>").html(d.book).appendTo(row);
            $("<td>").html(d.description).appendTo(row);
            var e = $("<td>").appendTo(row);
            $("<button>").html("VIEW").click(function(e) {
              window.location.href = d.url;
            }).appendTo(e);
          });
        } else {
          row = $("<tr>");
          $("<td>", {
            colspan: 4
          }).html("No Results Found.").appendTo(row);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $('#search').click(function() {
    var query = $('#search_id').val();
    load_data(query);
  });
});
```

As you can see, this makes use of a few more jQuery parts to help slimline your code. Additionally, we create a Click event callback when the button is created and added to the table.

You had a lot of improper HTML Syntax. My example does not replicate that. A Row Element should contain Cells and not other elements. Yes, you can do it, yet it's not good practice. This is why I removed them. If they are needed for some reason, you should provide a more complete example so it's clear why they are needed.